# Filter IQueryable by values from another database using EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, contains

I have two databases. I need to fetch some data (property values) from a first database and then filter out the records from a second database by those fetched values.

Now I am afraid that this operation may fail if the first database query will return too many records.

I generated an SQL query to read and checked that this query does not contain the filtering out by the values from the first table. So, it seems the LINQ to objects (instead of the LINQ to SQL) is applied in case of too many records. So, I decided to resort to using a HashSet instead of List to filter out values.

I had the following code:

```
IQueryable<Obj> query = ...
List<int> listOfSomeValues = ...
query = query.Where(obj => listOfSomeValues.Contains(obj.Prop));
```

Since the lookup operation in set should be faster than in list, I am changed my code to:

```
IQueryable<Obj> query = ...
List<int> listOfSomeValues = ...
var set = new HashSet<int>(listOfSomeValues);
query = query.Where(obj => set.Contains(obj.Prop));
```

Is there anything else I could do to improve the IQueryable filtering by values from another database using EF? Or is my only option is to resort to writing stored procedures which would make database do all the hard work?

Comment: Have you considered adding a view into the main database that points to a succinct representation of records from the second database where you want to fetch these ID/values from, basically enough data to determine which IDs or values you need? This way you could create an entity for a summary representation in your main DbContext that could be used to join against the relevant data. (using a Join rather than navigation properties)

Comment: @StevePy, makes sense. I will most probably do it. Thanks.